# ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton not responding to touchUpInside events

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I've experienced strange bug in Latest Xcode 11.0
My code:

```
let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .black)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.cornerRadius = 10
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(appleSignInButtonSelected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Selector never called, but if I change event to touchDown, everything works.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: Still the same issue in Xcode 11.2

Comment: Has anyone resolved this?

Answer (score 29):

I think it is apple bug. Use touchDown instead of touchUpInside.

Comment: `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` is a `UIControl`; it behaves differently from a real `UIButton`. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Should be the accepted solution... until Apple fixes this stupidity

Comment: No, it's not an issue from the Apple side its an issue from your side because you might be using tap gesture on your view.

Comment: wow great answer work for me

Answer (score 25):

I've experienced same issue. In my case I've had `UITapGestureRecognizer` attached to main view of the view controller. Setting property `cancelsTouchesInView` of the gesture recognizer to false helped.

Comment: That was my problem. I imagine a lot of people have a tap gesture recognizer on their login screen and will run into this problem too.

Comment: Seems this one was the correct reason for the issue but in my case the  **cancelsTouchesInView**  doesn't help. I manually added tap gesture when the keyboard raises and removed the tap gesture when the keyboard dismiss

Comment: Thanks man, I was going crazy figuring this out!

Comment: This resolved my problem and should be the accepted answer rather than use touchDown. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found out the best way to do this is to just use UITapGestureRecognizer

```
let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress))
button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Using addTarget(_:action:for:) with .touchDown would require the user to long tap the button (~1s longer than normal) before action is detected which is unusual.

Apple even rejected my app submission because "tapping the Sign in with Apple button did not produce any actions".

I recommend just using a tap gesture recognizer to avoid any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` did not receive any tap gestures at all (`down` or `upInside`) if there was a layout problem with its parent.

In my case, I had left out a constraint in one of the parent views, which caused the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` to be outside the frame of the parent view.

This was in a storyboard, so there was a red arrow and warning about it, but I had missed that initially. I found this by debugging the view hierarchy and noting the position of each of the ancestor views up the tree.

The fix is to ensure that there are constraints to keep the `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` within the frame of its ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

My problem with `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` was about not adding "Sign In With Apple" capability in target of the project.
[Screenshot with capability in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIdTw.png)

When you add `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate`, you need to check logs:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SignInViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### Edit 2020-06-16:

This issue has recently been fixed by Apple. The `AuthorizationAppleIDButtonButton` can now trigger the `UIControl.Event.touchUpInside`.

Although, unlike a UIButton, it doesn't bind `UIControl.Event.primaryActionTriggered` with `.touchUpInside`

---

### Original answer:

If you replace `touchUpInside` for `primaryAction` in [Apple's sample app for the sign-in (Juice)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple), it doesn't work either, so I guess there is an issue with the button itself.

I found no other solution than this workaround. The action will be triggered on `primaryActionTriggered` and the sign-in button will show a highlight animation as it should normally.

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SignInWithAppleButton: UIButton {
    private var action: (() -> Void)?
    private let authorizationAppleIDButtonButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            super.isHighlighted = isHighlighted
            authorizationAppleIDButtonButton.isHighlighted = isHighlighted
        }
    }

    class func make(action: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> SignInWithAppleButton {
        let button = SignInWithAppleButton(type: .custom)
        button.setup()
        button.action = action
        return button
    }

    private func setup() {
        addSubviewToFill(authorizationAppleIDButtonButton)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerAction), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        authorizationAppleIDButtonButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    @objc private func triggerAction() {
        action?()
    }
}
```